# Why is this string showing up from nowhere

Tags: c#, mysql

I am currently working on a project that creates/drops tables to MySql and also creates the "Posts" that go into each. When I try and run what I have it somehow takes my database name and tries to use it as a table. Any and all help is appreciated! I'm really confused how that value is moving from ConnectionString to SavePost

```
public class SavePost : ISavePost
{
    public static void CreatePostTable()
    {   
         ConnectionString myConnection = new ConnectionString();
        string cs = myConnection.cs;
        //Console.WriteLine(cs);
        using var con = new MySqlConnection(cs);
        con.Open();

        string stm = @"CREATE TABLE post(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, Text TEXT, Timestamp DATE)";

        using var cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, con);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    
    public void CreatePost(Post myPost)
    {
        ConnectionString myConnection = new ConnectionString();
        string cs = myConnection.cs;
        using var con = new MySqlConnection(cs);
        con.Open();

        string stm = @"INSERT INTO post(Id, Text, Timestamp) VALUES(@id, @text, @Timestamp)";
        
        using var cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", myPost.Id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Text", myPost.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeStamp", myPost.Timestamp);

        cmd.Prepare();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    void ISavePost(Post myPost)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    void ISavePost.SavePost(Post myPost)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Connection String (Only Place my data base name exists)

```
public class ConnectionString
{
    public string cs {get; set;}

    public ConnectionString()
    {
        string server = "ohunm00fjsjs1uzy.cbetxkdyhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
        string database = "z7h5wlemxfp9e62l"; //Database Name Here
        string port = "3306";
        string userName = "b0carrau6sztptpq";
        string password = "glfh8lqesdwi10tb";

        cs = $@"server = {server};user = {userName};database = {database};port = {port};password = {password};";
    }
}
```

Main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    //DeletePost.DropPostTable();
    //SaveBook.CreatePostTable();

    Post myPost = new Post(){Id = 1, Text = "Roll Tide"};

    myPost.Save.CreatePost(myPost);
}
```

Post(Not sure if needed, but thought it wouldn't hurt)

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id{get; set;}

    public string Text{get; set;}

    public DateTime Timestamp{get; set;}

    public ISavePost Save{get; set;}

    public Post()
    {
        Save = new SavePost();
    }
```

ERROR FEEDBACK

```
Unhandled exception. MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'z7h5wlemxfp9e62l.post' doesn't exist
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at mis331_pa3_abrush60.database.SavePost.CreatePost(Post myPost) in /Users/treyrush/Desktop/PA3/mis331-pa3-abrush60/database/SavePost.cs:line 45
   at mis331_pa3_abrush60.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/treyrush/Desktop/PA3/mis331-pa3-abrush60/Program.cs:line 17
```

Comment: you database is the default schema, so it is prepended to the table names. It is saying the table `post` doesn't exist in your database. Maybe because you commented out the line that creates it?

Comment: also, please change your passwords now

Comment: Just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](https://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fully qualified name of the table includes the database (schema) that it is in. So, if your database is named `bobby` and your table is named `posts`, you access that table using `bobby.posts`

Now, when connecting it is very common to specify the default schema, which you do. That saves the need to prepend the schema to the table name each time you name a table. However, internally, it is still used and for error messages it is very helpful to see the schema.

So when it says `Table 'z7h5wlemxfp9e62l.post' doesn't exist` that simply means the table `post` does not exist in database `z7h5wlemxfp9e62l`